# Find the general term.

Tags: functions, wave-equation

I tried to solve the wave equation:
[image]

After some calculation I reached at this step where I have to find the constant alpha.
[image: ![enter image description here]

1. For even value of n alpha is 0
2. For n =  1, 3, 9, 11, 17, 19 . . . . . . alpha is $\sqrt{2}$
3. For n =  5, 7, 13, 15, 21, 23 . . . . . . alpha is $-\sqrt{2}$

Can anyone help me to find the general term for 2 and 3?
I tried my best but failed. Please help.
I want something like $\frac{{(-1)^{something}}8\sqrt{2}}{{\pi^2}{n^2}}$

Comment: There are uncountably many sequences starting with the same first terms.

Comment: A very weird question. What is the source?

Comment: The first row starts with 1 and then adds 2, then 6, then 2, then 6, etc. The second row starts with 5 and does the same thing. Do you have any more info in this?

Comment: The first row contains all the numbers of the form 8k+1 and 8k+3. The second row contains numbers of the form 8k+5 and 8k+7

Comment: @William Barnes Yeah. I think that's called "physicist's induction" by some very mean people. ;)

Comment: I tried to solve a wave equation. For if n is odd then result to the constant 8*[sin(n*pi/4) + sin(3*n*pi/4)]/(pi*n)^2 gives me result like sqrt(2), sqrt(2), -sqrt(2), -sqrt(2), sqrt(2), sqrt(2),.............

Comment: And I want to generalize this.

Comment: And why on earth didn't you put that info about "wave equation" into your question?!

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sorry, I have added the details now.

Comment: As a simplification note, we have: $$\frac{8}{n^2\pi^2}\left(\sin\frac{n\pi}{4}+\sin\frac{3n\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{16}{n^2\pi^2}\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\cos\frac{n\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post as they are unsearchable and unreadable for those using certain browsers and platforms. Format using mathjax instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General term is:

$$f(x) = {-1}^{\lfloor2\{x / 8 \} \rfloor +1} $$

Here is the proof.

As mentioned by me in the comments the first row contains numbers of the form $8k+1,8k+3$ and the second row contains numbers of the form $8k+5,8k+7$

Case 1: First Row

8k+1 or 8k+3

{(8k+1)/8} or {(8k+3)/8} = 0.125 or 0.375

2{(8k+1)/8} or 2{(8k+3)/8} = 0.25 or 0.75

When you take the floor function it becomes 1 because floor(0.25 or 0.75) = 1

Therefore ${-1}^2  = 1$

Case 2: 2nd Row
{(8k+5)/8} or {(8k+7)/8} = 0.625 or 0.875

2{(8k+1)/8} or 2{(8k+3)/8} = 1.25 or 1.75

When you take the floor function it becomes 1 because floor(1.25 or 1.75) = 2

Therefore ${-1}^3 = -1$

Comment: For x = 9 it doesn't work,
4*(9/8)+1 = 4.5 +1= 4+1                         (-1)^5 = -1

Comment: @MirSazzatHossain It is the FLOOR function. So 4.5 becomes 5 then 5+1 =6. See that weird brackets are floor function.

Comment: @MirSazzatHossain It works for all x and I have proof of it.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused between floor and ceil.

Comment: @MirSazzatHossain Should I add the proof?

Comment: Please, It would be helpful.

Comment: @MirSazzatHossain I have edited it now. Do ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: Great sir. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I used *Mathematica* powerful function

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
   1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1}, x] // FullSimplify
```

$$\small f(x)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{4}\right)+\sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi  x}{4}\right)-\sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{5 \pi  x}{4}\right)-\sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{7 \pi  x}{4}\right)-2 \cos (\pi  x)-2\right)$$